# Template render error

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

I'm using nunjucks to render some variables:

```
    <div class="zoomable zoomable-{{ slide.index }}"> << this works

        {% if slide.temp is none %} << this doesn't
            {% include "layouts/"+{{slide.layout}} %} << this doesn't
        {% endif %}

    </div>
```

When the JS calls nunjucks.render, I get the following error:

`parseAggregate: expected colon after dict key` on the `include`

There are two issues with this:

- It's not supposed to skip the condition, because the property `temp`
  doesn't exist.
- Is it not letting me access the `slide` properties? Because
  `slide.layout` is valid

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also not sure if `none` is a valid comparison, haven't used nunjucks before. Maybe try `if not slide.temp`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you just need to remove the `curly brackets` i.e.

`{% include "layouts/" + slide.layout %}`

Comment: As it's already inside a nunjucks method structure it doesn't need to curly brackets to interpolate.